# ibm cloud target for organization and space

Tags: websphere, space, target, organization

Please how do I reset my region using ibmcloud cli?
I get the error:
No resource group targeted, use 'ibmcloud target -g RESOURCE_GROUP'

I don't know how to correct this error. I need to deploy a nodeJs application soon.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Here are the steps.

1)I logged in using: ibmcloud login
2)I unset my initial region ibmcloud target --unset-region
3)I had to login again using: ibmcloud login
4)After entering my email and password, I didn't select any region when it prompts that I should select region. Rather I hit the enter key.
5)After hitting enter, I tried connecting to my region using: ibmcloud target --cf
6)I had to visit the following link  to check for my organization : https://cloud.ibm.com/account/cloud-foundry
7)Meanwhile after entering ibmcloud target --cf it still prompted me to enter my region. So from the link I saw my organization and saw the region i.e. united kingdom eu-gb.
8)So back to the command prompt I selected 3 which was united kingdom eu-gb
9)And that was all
10)Then I deployed my application using : ibmcloud cf push